# TinyMCe content not showing up on editor for update

Tags: php, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE with PHP

I have a page with tinyMCe editor.What I am trying is that when user finished his working on the editor he clicks the save button and the form is submitted and the tinyMCE content is saved in the database and the tinyMCE content still remains their in the editor.

Now what I've done so far is.

I've a script History_View.php which contains the editor.
Another script History_Model.php which inserts the tinyMCE text in database.

There are two problems that are occuring.

1. When I click on save button after editing in my tinyMCE editor the text successfully goes to my History_Model.php but the data(i.e the content of tinyMCE) is not getting stored in the database.Although the statments look to run successfully and there is no error.Here is the code to insert in DB.$historyy is the content here.

   ```
   public static function setHistory($id,$historyy)
   {
       self::$connection=DBCon::ConnectToDB();         
       mysql_query("call UpdateCompanyHistory($id,".utf8_encode($historyy).")");
       mysql_close(self::$connection);         
       header("Location:History_View.php?data=".$historyy);
       exit();
   }
   ```
2. After the query work i used php header to append the content in the url and move back to my editor page(i.e History_View.php) and there i am trying to place that text again in the editor.When I place it back using

   ```
    echo"

    <script type='text/javascript'>

      function loadDefaultTinyMCEContent()
      {    
              tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('".$_GET['editorData']."');
      }
    </script>

    ";
   ```

[image]

Now this is how i edited my tinymce what the problem is that the picture shows up in the editor again after all the process but not the red text because the tinyMCE content is cut off i.e it is not returning the complete text.

```
  <p><img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Folder/Hyperion/Games.png" alt="" width="256" height="256" /><strong><span style="color:
```

Now I don't know why it is cutting the content and why it is not inserting it in the database.]

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL escaping the data before sending it to your db.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Also it is recommended to use mysqli on newer code instead of the old mysql.

Comment: the data gets entered in the mysql database the params I've mentioned were vice versa that is the history first then the id.One of the dumbest mistake I've ever made.
But still can't figure out the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your second problem: You should never ever attach the content to your url.
The length of the url is limited as you can see having a closer look on the content:

```
<p><img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Folder/Hyperion/Games.png" alt="" width="256" height="256" /><strong><span style="color:
```

This content is stripped obviously. You should work using ajax for example. Then you can get the content from the response and set it to you editor instance even without needing to relaod your full page.